# Configure screenshot folder in Cypress

Tags: cypress, mochawesome

I am using Cypress as my user interface test automation framework.
Currently my folder structure for spec file (logical organization of test files) is:

> ~/myAccount/header/header.spec.js
>
> ~/myAccount/footer/footer.spec.js
>
> ~/myAccount/mainTabs/home.spec.js

and so on...
Now when I configure my screenshot folder in cypress.json to screenshots and save screenshots of failed test cases, cypress internally creates a folder structure inside screenshots folder. For instance if a test fails in footer.spec.js, it saves the screenshot in

> ~/screenshots/myAccount/footer/footer.spec.js

I want to get rid of this recursive folder structure and save all screenshots inside screenshots folder (so that I can easily access these screenshots and add it to my mochawesome report).
Is there any way to do it ?
Any help will be appreciated and let me know if I was unable to put my question properly. I am willing to add more information.

Comment: why don't you specify in your cypress.json `"screenshotsFolder": '"screenshots",`

Comment: It will just configure the default root directory. Inside the root directory it will make sub directories based on your test case structure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [`Cypress` screenshot API](https://docs.cypress.io/api/plugins/after-screenshot-api.html#Usage):

for example:

```js
// cypress/plugins/index.js

const fs = require('fs')

module.exports = (on, config) => {
  on('after:screenshot', (details) => {
    // details will look something like this:
    // {
    //   size: 10248
    //   takenAt: '2018-06-27T20:17:19.537Z'
    //   duration: 4071
    //   dimensions: { width: 1000, height: 660 }
    //   multipart: false
    //   pixelRatio: 1
    //   name: 'my-screenshot'
    //   specName: 'integration/my-spec.js'
    //   testFailure: true
    //   path: '/path/to/my-screenshot.png'
    //   scaled: true
    //   blackout: []
    // }

    // example of renaming the screenshot file

    const newPath = '/new/path/to/screenshot.png'

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      fs.rename(details.path, newPath, (err) => {
        if (err) return reject(err)

        // because we renamed/moved the image, resolve with the new path
        // so it is accurate in the test results
        resolve({ path: newPath })
      })
    })
  })
}
```

You could also create symlinks if you wanted the image in two places, for example.

Comment: can you make sure your complete answer is visible. Looks like some mark up issue.

Comment: I don't think your solution will work because the event 'after:screenshot' only gets triggered when we call cy.screenshot(). For  my use case (successfully attach screenshot of failed TC to mochawesome) once I detect a TC fail (under event 'test:after:run') , I am not able to trigger cy.screenshot() (inside the test:after:run block.)

Comment: the event should still fire, see this docs page: https://docs.cypress.io/api/plugins/after-screenshot-api.html#Usage

Comment: I don't know if its a bug in Cypress or I am doing something wrong, but this event doesn't get fired in case of screenshot resulting from TC failure. I can clearly see it getting fired in case of cy.screenshot().

Comment: I will still accept your answer anyways because as per the documentation this should be the desired behavior.  Thanks @bkucera. Much help.

Comment: @trickster consider opening an issue if you have a reproducible example https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues